# ASP.net MVC + ASP.net Identity Seeding roles and users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In Migrations Configuration class, there is Seed method, and it looks like:

```
protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
        {
           var  roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
           var  userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(context)); 

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Administrator"))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Administrator"));
            }

            var user = new User {UserName = "someUserName"};


            if (userManager.FindByName("someUserName") == null)
            {
                var result = userManager.Create(user, "password");

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
                }    

            }
            }
```

And then in PM console I've run update-database, and it successfully  seeded  database, and in table AspNetUserRoles I can see that user someUserName and Administrator role are connected.

But when I put attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` above controller I've been redirected to log in page as if my user wasn't in that role, so I've  added line in my controller:

```
var x = _userManager.IsInRole(_userManager.FindByName("someUserName").Id, "Administrator");
```

And x is false. Why is this happening ? And how can I fix it ? And if this isn't proper way to seed database, which is ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try in your seed method

```
 context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Here's my guess at what is going on when lazy loading is disabled, the Roles property of the `IdentityUser` / `ApplicationUser` object is null or empty when the UserManager or UserStore accesses it because that collection was not manually loaded. The code then carries on like no roles have been assigned to the user when in fact that collection simply was never loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

at the end of Seed method.